# Can I make sure no one forks my GitHub repo but still allow the work to be seen by recruiters?

Tags: github, repository

I am now building portfolio to get my first tech job. I would like for any recruiters/potential employers to see my code in case they want to see how I am putting things together but I don't want anyone to be able to fork or copy my work.

How is this possible?

If I have a private GitHub repo does that mean that you can see the repo but just not the inner contents? I have looked at the GitHub documentation already.

Comment: You'd have to have a private repo then invite them as collaborators. If a repo is public, it's visible to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a private GitHub repo does that mean that you can see the repo but just not the inner contents?

If you can access a repository (public or private), that means you can read its content and/or clone it (and read its content locally)

You would need to setup a private repository dedicated to show your file
*names*, meaning a collection of files with:

- dummy content
- the exact names and folder structure than your actual projects.

That way, you can share to select collaborator access to that "showcase" repository, without compromising the sensitive content of your actual project repositories.